# String interpreted as Boolean

Tags: java, json

Here's my code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    String temp = reader.readLine();
    if(temp!=null)
        result = new JSONObject(temp);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you see, I assign String to String type object, but when code runs, `result="true"` and I get exception:

> Value true of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject

That's frustrating.. should I cast or use `.toString()` for a String object? Why it's automatically converted to Boolean?

**Update**
I've figured out, that this is not a Java issue, but JSONObject constructor is not receiving valid JSONObject.

Comment: Well, `true` is not a JSON Object, it is a JSON boolean...

Comment: What is the value of variable `temp`? Is it probably `true`?

Comment: I mentioned it in my post already: result="true"

Comment: Shall not be there braces? new JSONObject("{result: true}");

Comment: @fge what do you meat it's not a JSON Object? The question is, why the new JSONObject(temp) constructor interprets temp as Boolean, when it's a String?

Comment: @LeosLiterak no, there are no braces.. And the question is not about the braces..

Comment: I updated my comment. What is temp value? Is it JSON formatted object?

Comment: @LeosLiterak please, read my initial post carefully - temp="true", that's what api returns me, and I can't change it.

Comment: Here's how a valid JSON object looks like: `{"a":"hello", "b":true}`. So it's enclosed in braces, and has a number of keys, each having a value. `true` doesn't qualify. That's a bit like doing `new Date("hello world")`. "hello world" doesn't represent a valid date, whatever the way you look at it.

Comment: @JBNizet question is NOT about validity of received JSON..

Comment: @insomnium_ you are confusing between many, many things here. `new JSONObject(String)` will try and read a _JSON Object_ from the `String` input. But here your JSON value is boolean value `true`, it is NOT a JSON object. The behaviour is therefore expected!

Comment: The fact is, you're trying to create a JSON object from a string which doesn't represent a valid JSON object. So it can't work. Just like if you did `new Integer("hello")`.

Comment: @insomnium_ please show us, what you pass as argument to constructor

Comment: Ok, I got it, it's not a Java issue, converting String to Boolean. It's because JSONObject constructor gets invalid argument. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is **expected**.  Quoting from [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

> Strings do not need to be quoted at all if they do not begin with a
>   quote or single quote, and if they do not contain leading or trailing
>   spaces, and if they do not contain any of these characters: `{ } [ ] /
>   \ : , = ; #` and if they do not look like numbers and if they are not
>   the reserved words `true`, `false`, or `null`.

Answer (score 2):

`"true"` is not a `JSONObject`. A `JSONObject` is

> an unordered collection of name/value pairs.

quoting from the same source as @devnull. Java is not interpreting the `String` `result` as a `Boolean`, rather the JSON value represented by the String `"true"` is correctly interpreted as a JSON boolean. Clearly, it is not a collection of name/value pairs, which is denoted as @Leos Literak suggested using curly braces, colons and semicolons:

```
{ key : "value"; otherkey : true }
```

I hope this helps. The term 'object' is used very differently in Java and JSON.